# Possible to create a matrix of INPUTs using CSS and a TABLE?

Tags: html, css

Let's say we want to make a tic-tac-toe game. Is in possible with three TRs, each with only one TD containing three INPUTs? Or does each TR require three TDs, each TD containing one INPUT?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  You can do it either way.  What exactly would you like the table to look like?

Comment: Either way would be fine if you apply enough styling to make it look like a tic tac toe board - I can't really understand what the problem is. And there's loads of other ways to do it, perhaps CSS grid 3x3 would make it more straightforward to style - fewer layers.

Comment: @DCR: The question is, how to keep the inputs side-by-side if each one is not in its own TD?

Comment: a tic tac toe board is 3 by 3.  How does having just three inputs suppose to work.  Please edit your question and provide clearer description of the problem you are having.

Comment: @DCR.  3 TRs x 3 inputs per TR = 9.   "three TRs, each with only one TD containing three INPUTs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what you want to do.

```css
input{
width:50px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type='text' value="X">
         <input type='text' value="O">
         <input type='text' value="X">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type='text'>        
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type='text'>        
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type='text'>        
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, my inputs  were displaying vertically inside the TD, not three across.